# Preparing a GLM logistic regression: choosing the factors

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, modeling

I am researching the incidence of pain after an operation, according to anaesthetic type. Univariate analysis is inconclusive, but I would like to proceed to multivariate analysis.

I have done some GLM on R before, but not for logistic regression. My main issues that the more I read, the more I think that I might be doing something stupid. So here it goes:

I am starting with all factors included in the model, to predict pain (yes or no)

```
Call:
glm(formula = pain ~ age + bmi + sex + pain_physio + 
    preWOMACpain + pain_rest + anaesthesia.F, family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
    data = clean)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.2311  -0.5124  -0.3949  -0.2876   2.5053  

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)    -1.286136   2.965939  -0.434   0.6646  
age            -0.031257   0.035777  -0.874   0.3823  
bmi            -0.017274   0.040200  -0.430   0.6674  
sexm            0.171867   0.553194   0.311   0.7560  
pain_physio    -0.008165   0.108246  -0.075   0.9399  
preWOMACpain    0.171939   0.086763   1.982   0.0475 *
pain_rest       0.162063   0.101212   1.601   0.1093  
anaesthesia.FS -0.964222   0.570588  -1.690   0.0911 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 113.72  on 164  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 103.56  on 157  degrees of freedom
  (27 observations deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 119.56

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

Now, I had been told to choose those factors with a high Pr(>|z|) value and eliminate them from the equation. In that case I end up with:

```
glm(formula = pain ~ pain_rest + preWOMACpain + 
    anaesthesia.F, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = clean)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.0563  -0.5071  -0.4018  -0.2869   2.4211  

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)    -3.78050    0.91893  -4.114 3.89e-05 ***
pain_rest       0.17388    0.08694   2.000   0.0455 *  
preWOMACpain    0.16304    0.07717   2.113   0.0346 *  
anaesthesia.FS -1.06303    0.53841  -1.974   0.0483 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 119.30  on 170  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 109.28  on 167  degrees of freedom
  (21 observations deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 117.28

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

These are the last factors that have a Pr(>|z|) value < 5

however, am I doing this correct: if I use AIC, or even deviance, I come to a different conclusion:

```
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model: binomial, link: logit

Response: postWOMACpain_6.C

Terms added sequentially (first to last)


                  Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev Pr(>Chi)  
    NULL                            164     113.72           
    age            1  2.24949       163     111.47  0.13366  
    bmi            1  0.03535       162     111.44  0.85087  
    sex            1  0.00177       161     111.44  0.96640  
    pain_physio    1  0.25859       160     111.18  0.61109  
    preWOMACpain   1  2.62798       159     108.55  0.10500  
    pain_rest      1  2.01041       158     106.54  0.15622  
    anaesthesia.F  1  2.97778       157     103.56  0.08442 .
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

would mean that I discard bmi, sex, then:

```
              Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev Pr(>Chi)
NULL                            166     114.18         
age            1  2.20824       165     111.97   0.1373
pain_physio    1  0.31823       164     111.65   0.5727
preWOMACpain   1  2.16295       163     109.49   0.1414
pain_rest      1  1.79268       162     107.70   0.1806
anaesthesia.F  1  2.64925       161     105.05   0.1036

discard pain_physio, then pain_rest:

              Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev Pr(>Chi)  
NULL                            170     119.30           
age            1   2.7036       169     116.60  0.10012  
preWOMACpain   1   2.7246       168     113.87  0.09881 .
anaesthesia.F  1   2.2374       167     111.64  0.13471  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> summary (m)

Call:
glm(formula = postWOMACpain_6.C ~ age + preWOMACpain + anaesthesia.F, 
    family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = clean)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.0251  -0.5099  -0.4119  -0.3244   2.5313  

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)    -0.26618    2.40644  -0.111   0.9119  
age            -0.04421    0.03452  -1.281   0.2002  
preWOMACpain    0.13919    0.07659   1.817   0.0692 .
anaesthesia.FS -0.76901    0.52310  -1.470   0.1415  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 119.30  on 170  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 111.63  on 167  degrees of freedom
  (21 observations deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 119.63
```

So what is the appropriate statistical method? Choosing the Pr>z value OR according to deviance? IF the latter, what happens when one factor happens to influence the deviance a lot, but then has a high Pr>z value?

sorry for the long post,

thanks so much

stephen

Comment: What's your goal in removing the factors from the model?  What do you hope to learn or improve from the exercise?  These approaches are rules of thumb, they don't really have a statistical justification.  It's not surprising they should lead you down different paths.

Comment: @matthew drury. You are right, i understand your point. I am exploring which factors may explain development pain in my research, especially anaesthesia. Groups are well matched except slightly for prewomac which has a slightly higher incidence in one group. This seems to have an opposing effect. I also am interested in what is best practice, as am now getting confused the more i read